# Installing 3rd party jar

Tags: java, maven

My POM has a 3rd party jar (doesn't exist on maven repository)

When I try to use flyway db migration is says

```
 mvn clean flyway:migrate -Dflyway.configFile=myFlywayConfig.properties
```

> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 1.086 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2018-04-17T10:00:12+01:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 11M/155M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myP: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project myProject:myP:war:1.0: Failure to find
>   com.fisglobal:jdbc:jar:3.5.3.4 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
>   was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
>   until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
>   -> [Help 1]

So I installed it using

```
 mvn install:install-file -Dfile=src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/com.fisglobal.jdbc_3.5.3.4.jar -DgroupId=com.fisglobal.jdbc -DartifactId=jdbc -Dversion=3.5.3.4 -Dpackaging=jar
```

and it says build success but if I run the first command again I get the same error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The groupId in install is wron it must be `-DgroupId=com.fisglobal`

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/com.fisglobal.jdbc_3.5.3.4.jar -DgroupId=com.fisglobal -DartifactId=jdbc -Dversion=3.5.3.4 -Dpackaging=jar
```